# Shopify theme how to check product description text

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

In Shopify theme for Product details page we have something like

```
{{ product.description }}
```

to show product description, now I want to check for a specific text within the description and based on that do something, for example, something like

```
if( {{ product.description }} hastext "On Sale"){ 
// do something 
}
else{
 do something 
}
```

I want to know the syntax for above implementation in product-template.liquid
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `contains` operator.

Please refer to the Shopify documentation: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/operators

In code:

```
{%- if product.description contains "On Sale" -%}
  // do something
{%- else -%}
  // do something
{%- endif -%}
```